# jenkins threshold plugin shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have one bash/shell script to check a set of constraints in my project. The output of this script is the number of errors/violations found in the source code (Non Java project).

I'm looking for a Jenkins plugin to check this script output and notify a fail depending on a threshold. It's the same functionality as [Violations plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations) + Checkstyle, PMD, etc, but the datasource should be a custom script.

I have been searching for a while, but anything fits this requirement.

Do you know if this plugin exists?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [the Warnings plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin), it describes how to "Write a new parser that should be included in the warnings plug-in" and to "Write a new standalone parser that will be deployed in a new plug-in"

It also have a "Failure threshold to mark a build as unstable"